# How to remove element from List<string[]> and put it at the end of the list?

Tags: list, c#-4.0

I have a

```
List<string[]> list which contains this data:

SEC Code (list[0][0])
Status   (list[0][1])
ALL (list[1][0])
None (list[1][1])
```

The data is like this:

```
SEC Code ALL
Status   None
```

I want to remove "SEC Code" and "ALL" and put them at the end of the list. I tried list.Remove, but it works for

```
List<string> and not for List<string[]>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried `list.Remove`, but it works for `List<string>` and not for `List<string[]>`.

This is because `list.Remove` compares items for equality using the `Equals(object)` which arrays do not override. In order for an array to be considered equal to another array from the `Equals(object)`'s point of view, it must be the same array instance.

In order to remove `"SEC Code"` and `"ALL"` from an inner array you need to build a new array that is shorter by one item, like this:

```
var toRemove = new HashSet<string> {"SEC Code", "ALL"};
var newList = list.Select(array =>
    array.Where(item => !toRemove.Contains(item)).ToArray()
).ToList();
```

The code above produces a list of string arrays from which all `"SEC Code"` and `"ALL"` strings have been removed.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. The suggested code keeps {"SEC Code", "ALL"} and deletes {"Status", "None"}.

Comment: @user2142250 That's strange. Are you sure you didn't miss the exclamation point in front of `toRemove.Contains(item)`?

Comment: @user2142250 That is strange, because I see the opposite - only the `"Status"` and `"None"` are kept ([demo](http://ideone.com/9uHIpE))

Comment: Please look at this data:

    SEC Code (list[0][0])
    Status   (list[0][1])
    ALL      (list[1][0])
    None     (list[1][1])

SEC Code and ALL are not grouped together. It's like: {"SEC Code", "Status"},  {"ALL", "None"}.

Comment: @user2142250 That is what I have in my demo - see lines 10 and 11.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you included a demo until now. Yes, your code works perfectly well. Something happened when I added your code to mine, which includes lots of other logic. I'll debug it. I've accepted your answer.